# TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, validation

code returns a error TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined,

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState();

const classes = useStyles();
const [fields, setFields] = useState([''
]);


const onChangeHandler = (e, i) => {                            
    const { name , value } = e.target
    const currentFields = [...fields];
    currentFields[i] = value;
    setFields(currentFields)
}

//Validators

const [errors, setErrors] = useState ('');

const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let errors = {};
    if (!category.trim()){
        errors.category="Select Type of Category is Required"
    }
    if (!fields.trim()){
        errors.fields="Field is Required/Remove empty Fields"
    }
    setErrors(errors)
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0){
        formSubmit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your `category` state initial value is undefined.

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState();
```

You should provide a valid string value for it.

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
```

The alternative is to use null-checks

```
if (category && !category.trim()){
  errors.category="Select Type of Category is Required"
}
```

Or Optional Chaining

```
if (!category?.trim()){
  errors.category="Select Type of Category is Required"
}
```

**Note:** Any other time you are updating the `category` state you should also ensure the state invariant is maintained, i.e. it should likely always be a string, or apply the same alternative checks when accessing *that* state.

Comment: first one on string value for category works. but the fields are returning as not a function, thankyou for your answer sir.

Comment: @JasperBumatay `fields` is an array, so there is no `trim` method to call. Did you mean to check the `fields` array length (`if (!fields.length) {.....`), or something more like checking that each field value is a trimmed, non-empty string (`if (fields.length && fields.every(el => el.trim())) {.....`)? Can you clarify what you mean by "fields are returning as not a function"?